# Using .Net to access Google Sheets with a service account generates a "The caller does not have permission [403]" error

Tags: .net, api, service, google-sheets, account

I'm using .Net (and I have installed the NuGet package) to access Google Sheets using a service account. I have a Google API account, created the service account and even have a test sheet to work with. I have included the JSON file which describes the credentials that I downloaded from the service account I created. Everything seems to work except when I use the Execute method call I get the following error:

> The caller does not have permission [403] Message[The caller does not
>   have permission] Location[ - ] Reason[forbidden] Domain[global]

at `` Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.<ParseResponse>d__34.MoveNext() ``

I have turned on global access for the service account as well, but it still doesn't work. I tried to share the service account with the sheet, but there doesn't seem to be any way to do that.

My code looks like this:

```
string[] Scopes = { SheetsService.Scope.SpreadsheetsReadonly };
string ApplicationName = "My Unit Test";

GoogleCredential sac;

        using (var stream = new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            sac = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream).CreateScoped(Scopes);
        }


// Create Google Sheets API service.
        var service = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = sac,
            ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
        });

String spreadsheetId = "1_aeTu4YxDKrqDBvCNR1awyo_7WDha0JBVo1jLxsz3pA";
        String range = "Export!A2:E";
        SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.GetRequest request = service.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(spreadsheetId, range);

ValueRange response = request.Execute(); // Exception thrown here
```

I need the Execute to successfully log in and access the Google Sheet I setup. Has anyone seen this or know a way around it?

Answer (score 1):

Nobody responded and I found the fix on my own. The gmail account I was using for testing was a specialized work domain. It didn't allow me to share the sheet correctly. So, I setup a new google account, added all the apis and service accounts in. Added the proper role to the service account. Generated the new json private key. Created a sheet with that new account and shared it with the new service account … it works. IMPORTANT, you must share the sheet with the service account or it will not work.